is it possible to set the initial coordinates of the node in the ngx-graph library
Hello everyone I wrote code to visualize the graph using ngx-graph, but I ran into a problem, I need to center the main nodes (in my data they are marked with a specific tag). Are there any options to implement this?
For example in d3.js I can set the coordinates before rendering, which allowed me to get rid of this problem.  But unfortunately I need to solve this problem using the ngx-graph library.
what i have now
In the screenshot, the nodes with a yellow background should be located in the center (under each other) Like this:
what i need(
